# How to get list of existing routes in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to get list of existing routes in Ember?
Like the way of 'rake routes' command in Rails.

Answer (score 4):

You can access all existing routes with `App.Router.router.recognizer.names` or if you only want the route names use `Ember.keys(App.Router.router.recognizer.names)`

This is though not recommended for production, only for debugging purposes.

And [here an example](http://jsbin.com/ekolod/2/edit), please check the console.

Hope it helps.